# Java: Gson and encoding

Tags: java, json, encoding, gson

I am using Umlauts (ä,ü,ö) in a Gson that I need to pass via Http Post Body.

Unfortuenately, my web app will return null if the Umlauts are not converted somehow, and they are not.

content-type is "application/json"

How do I tell Gson to encode the Umlauts properly (the Umlauts are in the values, not the keys)?

Comment: "my web app will return null if the Umlauts are not converted somehow" so the problem is with web-app.

Comment: It is an MVC 4 app if that helps. Should accept Umlauts without encoding in the body or not?

Comment: `application/json` must accept Unicode (and therefore Umlauts.) From the [spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt): _"JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode. The default encoding is UTF-8."_ If the web application does not accept this, it does not accept JSON.

Comment: My web application does accept and decode JSON very well and automatically, it is just with these special characters that the controller methods recieve null as parameter from the http body. Other than that it's fine. Since I already tried putting putting ("charset", "utf-8") in the request header and it also failed (leaving the Umlauts as-is), this means my MVC4 app doesn't support UTF-8, right?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem passing umlaut to a web service in JSON. 
The webserver could not decode correctly those characters. By configuring the HttpClient for UTF encoding the problem disappeared, here is my working code:

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParams, HTTP.UTF_8);
HttpProtocolParams.setHttpElementCharset(httpParams, HTTP.UTF_8);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(serverURL);
StringEntity str = null;
String jsonString = gson.toJson(yourdata);
str = new StringEntity(jsonString, HTTP.UTF_8);
request.setEntity(str);
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
client.execute(request);
```

Comment: Thanks, the httpParams were the missing part in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to set

```
charset=UTF-8
```

to force the encoding.

Comment: unfortunately this did not help (setting it in http header)

Answer (score 0):

You can encode Umlauts into decimal entities before passing to gson.
from json you can decode these entities.

```
/* encode unicode characters in a given string */
    private static String getEncodedText(String text) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char ch = text.charAt(i);
            int codePoint = text.codePointAt(i);

            if (codePoint >= 0 && codePoint <= 126 
                    && (codePoint != 34 && codePoint != 39
                            && codePoint != 60 && codePoint != 62
                            && codePoint != 94 && codePoint != 96 && codePoint != '_')) {
                sb.append(ch);
                continue;
            }


            sb.append(convertToEntity(String.valueOf(codePoint)));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }


    public static String convertToEntity(String decimalValue) {
        return "&#" + decimalValue+ ";";
    }
```

Comment: How would I do that? Normally I just to toGson(object).

Comment: before setting value to object variable you want to convert ti json apply above method to encode string.